# Check if column exists and is of specific type

Tags: sql-server

Currently I have written some script which checks if column exists.  However, I also need to check if the column is of a specific type (in this case a `UniqueIdentifier`).

```
IF COL_LENGTH('Comments', 'Id1') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Comments
    ADD Id1 int null
END
GO
```

So how can I also check in the `IF` statement for `UniqueIdentifier` data type

Comment: You should use information schema to identify this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between the cases that (1) it exists and is uniqueidentifier (2) it exists and is some other type and (3) it doesn't exist? Or do you just need to know that it is (1)/(2) with no distinction or (3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this way

```
IF COL_LENGTH('Comments', 'Id1') IS NULL AND 'Uniqueidentifier' IN (
SELECT data_type
FROM information_schema.Columns
WHERE table_name = 'Comments' AND 
  column_name = 'Id1')
BEGIN 
  ALTER TABLE Comments
  ADD Id1 int null
END
GO
```